# How to include an IF condition to stop sending duplicate emails in google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following script for sending emails in google sheets. "Email_Sent" is inserted in column 36 to prevent sending a duplicate email. For some reason the script repeats the sending of the email. Come someone please assist in telling me why the script isn't working as it should?
Thanks

```
/**
 * Sends emails from spreadsheet rows.
 */
function sendEmails() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const dsh = ss.getSheets()[0];//repl with getshbyname
  const drg = dsh.getRange(2, 1, dsh.getLastRow() - 1, 36);
  const vs = drg.getValues();
  const tsh = ss.getSheets()[1];//repl with getshbyname
  const tmpl = tsh.getRange('A1').getValue();
  vs.forEach((r,i) => {
    let emailSent = r[35]; 
    let status = r[10];  
    if (status == 'PRICE ONLY' && emailSent != 'EMAIL_SENT') { 
    MailApp.sendEmail(r[9], 'SUPERMIX QUOTATION',fillInTemplateFromObject(tmpl, r) );//if last paramenter is the options object then you are missing the  null for the body. but since fillInTemplateFromObject is undefined I can not know that
    dsh.getRange(2 + i, 36).setValue('EMAIL_SENT');
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  });
}
/**
 * Replaces markers in a template string with values define in a JavaScript data object.
 * @param {string} template Contains markers, for instance ${"Column name"}
 * @param {object} data values to that will replace markers.
 *   For instance data.columnName will replace marker ${"Column name"}
 * @return {string} A string without markers. If no data is found to replace a marker,
 *   it is simply removed.
 */
function fillInTemplateFromObject(tmpl, data) {
  var email = tmpl;
  // Search for all the variables to be replaced, for instance ${"Column name"}
  var templateVars = tmpl.match(/\$\{\"[^\"]+\"\}/g);

  // Replace variables from the template with the actual values from the data object.
  // If no value is available, replace with the empty string.
  for (var r = 0; templateVars && r < templateVars.length; ++r) {
    // normalizeHeader ignores ${"} so we can call it directly here.
    var variableData = data[normalizeHeader(templateVars[r])];
    email = email.replace(templateVars[r], variableData || '');
  }

  return email;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function sendEmails() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const dsh = ss.getSheets()[0];//repl with getshbyname
  const drg = dsh.getRange(2, 1, dsh.getLastRow() - 1, 36);
  const vs = drg.getValues();
  const tsh = ss.getSheets()[1];//repl with getshbyname
  const tmpl = tsh.getRange('A1').getValue();
  vs.forEach((r,i) => {
    let emailSent = r[35]; 
    let status = r[10];  
    if (status == 'PRICE ONLY' && emailSent != 'EMAIL_SENT') { 
    MailApp.sendEmail(r[?], 'SUPERMIX QUOTATION',fillInTemplateFromObject(tmpl, r) );//if last paramenter is the options object then you are missing the  null for the body. but since fillInTemplateFromObject is undefined I can not know that
    dsh.getRange(2 + i, 36).setValue('EMAIL_SENT');
    }
  });
}
```

You code example has a few undefined variables and/or objects which make it impossible to provide a complete solution.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, yes this works for me, prevents sending duplicate emails. However can you please take a look at the code for fillInTemplateFromObject(). I should have included this in the original post.

Comment: I have updated the script with the code you suggested and the email is sending as I want however is not picking up the data from the template. Thanks very much for any help you can provide. Regards